# Sarrus Rule with LaTeX

Tags: matrices

Is there a way to create a new command with 9 arguments `({a_{11}},{a_{12}},{a_{13}},{a_{21}},{a_{22}},{a_{23}},{a_{31}},{a_{32}},{a_{33}})` that has as output a matrix with the Sarrus Rule? For instance: to obtain 
[image]

just use the command that we will call `sarrus`: 
`\sarrus{-k}{k-1}{1}{0}{k-1}{k}{2}{0}{1}`.

If it is possible i want to use the command `sarrus` in math mode just like `matrix` for istance.

Comment: Do you *really* think that Sarrus' rule is to be taught? I don't.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility, based on `pstricks` and `xparse`. The values in the matrix are given as a list of 9 elements, separated by a comma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node,  auto-pst-pdf} 
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\sarrus%
{>{ \SplitArgument{8}{,}} m }
{\sarrusaux #1}

\NewDocumentCommand\sarrusaux{mmmmmmmmm}{%
\begin{postscript}
\begin{array}{|*{3}{c}|cc}
\Rnode{a11}{#1} & \Rnode{a12}{#2} & \Rnode{a13}{#3} & \Rnode{b14}{#1} & \Rnode{b15}{#2}\\
\Rnode{a21}{#4} & \Rnode{a22}{#5} & \Rnode{a23}{#6}  & \Rnode{b24}{#4} & \Rnode{b25}{#5} \\
\Rnode{a31}{#7} & \Rnode{a32}{#8} & \Rnode{a33}{#9} & \Rnode{b34}{#7} & \Rnode{b35}{#8}
\end{array}
\psset{linecolor=red,  linewidth=0.3pt, nodesep=1pt}
\ncline{a11}{a33}\ncline{a12}{b34}\ncline{a13}{b35}
\psset{linecolor=blue}
\ncline{a31}{a13}\ncline{a32}{b14}\ncline{a33}{b15}
\end{postscript}
}%

\begin{document}

\[ \sarrus{-k,  k-1 , 1 , 0 , k-1, k , 2 , 0 , 1} \]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bernard this is the solution I need but it doesn't work because of auto-pst-pdf also in a new tex document.

Comment: To compile pstricks code with pdflatex, you have to launch pdflatex with the `--enable-write18` switch if you're under MiKTeX, `shell-escape` for TeX Live or MacTeX. You also can compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Wait I think we can find a better solution with tikzpicture together! I have this: 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (a) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=|,row sep=.5em,column sep=.5em]{
  a_{11} & a_{12}  & a_{13} & a_{11} & a_{12}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22}  & a_{23} & a_{21} & a_{22}  \\
  a_{31} & a_{32}  & a_{33} & a_{31} & a_{32}  \\
  };
   \draw[red] (a-1-1) -- (a-3-3);
   \draw[red] (a-1-2) -- (a-3-4);
   \draw[red] (a-1-3) -- (a-3-5); 
   
   \draw[blue] (a-1-3) -- (a-3-1);
   \draw[blue] (a-1-4) -- (a-3-2);
   \draw[blue] (a-1-5) -- (a-3-3);   
 \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: Now.. I need two more things from this.. add another ' delimiter '  between the 3 and the 4 column... and then automate all of it with a 9-arguments command. Can you help?

Comment: I'll try to see , but I don't know well tikz. The main advantage with the pstricks solution is that you start from an ordinary array environment, and just add some pstricks code to draw lines.