# How to draw lines over a matrix to represent Sarrus’s rule

Tags: matrices

I am trying to make this matrix with the lines over it, as the image:

[image]

I know the matrix environment but I don’t know how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What you try so far? see if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257043/ can help you.

Comment: I suggest also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333893/sarrus-rule-with-latex and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476347/determinant-with-tikz-latex for example.